# Ajax based progress bar

Tags: c, ajax, linux, cgi

I am developing a progress bar using Ajax. My client side code is working fine, but I have issue at server side. I am using C based CGI.

```
if(i == inc && pb_inc<=100)
{
fptr = fopen("progress_bar.txt", "w");
fprintf(fptr,"%d", j);
fclose(fptr);
pb_inc++;
}
```

basically I am increasing progress bar after certain number of bytes. What I see here is that the CGI doesn't let display any data to text file until it has sent all the data to file one by one.

i have referred to http://www.redips.net/javascript/ajax-progress-bar/

Any idea whats happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does calling `fflush(fptr)` improve things? I'm assuming the client side is requesting `progress_bar.txt`, which may not be updating as you expect.

Comment: No, fflush(fptr) doesn't change anything. Yes, client is requesting for progress_bar.txt, although the text file gets updated but it doesn't get available for reading at the time of update, only after its DONE updating, it is available.

Comment: @Punit If it doesn't change anything, why did you accept it as the answer?  Just another reason stack isn't the best.